# how split string to array oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How split string to array oracle?

```
'3/5/7'
```

Result:

```
15
```

Comment: Would the strings _always_ have exactly three numbers?  Can you add more sample data?  Note that Oracle formerly doesn't really support arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xmltable` to generate rows from string :

More numbers are accepted.

```
select sum(to_number(column_value)) as SOMME from xmltable(REPLACE('3/5/7', '/', ','));
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/90OjuODi)

Answer (score 1):

Generate dummy rows (below: `SELECT ROWNUM pos FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10`), more than the # of elements you expect to ever have. Here I used 10, you could make it 100 or 1000 if you wanted. Label each row numerically with ROWNUM. Then use that as an operand into the `SUBSTR` function. This can be done with `SUBSTR_REGEXP` too perhaps more concisely. This will tokenize your string. Then all you have to do is aggregate the results with SUM.

```
SELECT SUM(item)
  FROM (SELECT value,
               pos,
               SUBSTR(value,INSTR(value,'/',1,pos)+1,INSTR(value,'/',1,pos+1)-(INSTR(value,'/',1,pos)+1)) item
          FROM (SELECT '/'||'3/5/7'||'/' value from dual),
               (SELECT ROWNUM pos FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10))
 WHERE item IS NOT NULL
```